# Use the branch and bound algorithm to solve the TSP in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I made a Matlab script on my own for solving the traveling salesman problem applying the branch and bound algorithm.

1) In my example, I have 4 cities (A, B, C, D). I defined directly the distance matrix.

2) In another file (generate_distance_matrix) I wrote a little code for loading an excel file (Test). In that excel file I randomly choose some coordinates (x1,x2):

**How I can combine these both scripts? And how I can adapt the script in a iterative manner? Because at the moment I wrote my code (TSP_test) just for 4 cities.**

The working steps for my script are: Reduce the initial cost matrix (row and column reduction)

Evaluating the next node. For example (A=>B)

Set M(A, B) = 0

Set row A and column B to inf

Set M(B, A) = inf

Evaluate the cost value

Repeat these steps for the next node.

I hope someone could help me with my problems.

When something is not clear in my script please ask.

Here you can see the script for the branch and bound algorithm:

```
    % Script for solving the TSP by using branch and bound
% Step 1: Write the initial cost matrix and reduce it (Row reduction and
% Column reduction

% Step 2: From the reduced matrix from step 1, M(A,B) = 0
% Set row A and column B to inf
% Set M(B,A) to inf
clear all
clc
% Rows from the inital cost matrix
% There are 4 cities (city A...city D)
A = [inf, 4, 12, 7];
B = [5, inf, inf, 18];
C = [11, inf, inf, 6];
D = [10, 2, 3, inf];

% Initial cost matrix representing the distances between the cities
% for example: the distance between city A and B is 4
M_initial_cost_matrix = [A; B; C; D];

% Reduce the initial cost matrix
row_reduction = min(M_initial_cost_matrix, [], 2);

row_reduction(isinf(row_reduction)) = 0;

M_row_reduced = M_initial_cost_matrix - row_reduction;

column_reduction = min(M_row_reduced);

M_reduced_1 = M_row_reduced - column_reduction;

M_reduced_1(isnan(M_reduced_1)) = inf;

% Evaluate the cost value
cost_1 = sum(row_reduction) + sum(column_reduction)

% Distance between city A and B (node 2)
M_reduced = M_reduced_1

M_reduced(1, :) = inf;
M_reduced(:, 2) = inf;
M_reduced(2, 1) = inf;

row_reduction = min(M_reduced, [], 2);

row_reduction(isinf(row_reduction)) = 0;

M_row_reduced = M_reduced - row_reduction;

column_reduction = min(M_row_reduced);

column_reduction(isinf(column_reduction)) = 0;

M_reduced_2 = M_row_reduced - column_reduction;

M_reduced_2(isnan(M_reduced_2)) = inf

cost_2 = cost_1 + sum(row_reduction) + sum(column_reduction) + M_reduced_1(1, 2)

% Distance between city A and C (node 3)
M_reduced = M_reduced_1

M_reduced(1, :) = inf;
M_reduced(:, 3) = inf;
M_reduced(3, 1) = inf;

row_reduction = min(M_reduced, [], 2);

row_reduction(isinf(row_reduction)) = 0;

M_row_reduced = M_reduced - row_reduction;

column_reduction = min(M_row_reduced);

column_reduction(isinf(column_reduction)) = 0;

M_reduced_3 = M_row_reduced - column_reduction;

M_reduced_3(isnan(M_reduced_3)) = inf;

cost_3 = cost_1 + sum(row_reduction) + sum(column_reduction) + M_reduced_1(1, 3)

% Distance between city A and D (node 4)
M_reduced = M_reduced_1

M_reduced(1, :) = inf;
M_reduced(:, 4) = inf;
M_reduced(4, 1) = inf;

row_reduction = min(M_reduced, [], 2);

row_reduction(isinf(row_reduction)) = 0;

M_row_reduced = M_reduced - row_reduction;

column_reduction = min(M_row_reduced);

column_reduction(isinf(column_reduction)) = 0;

M_reduced_4 = M_row_reduced - column_reduction;

M_reduced_4(isnan(M_reduced_4)) = inf;

cost_4 = cost_1 + sum(row_reduction) + sum(column_reduction) + M_reduced_1(1, 4)

% Lowest cost
lowest_cost = min([cost_2, cost_3, cost_4])

% Distance between city A, C, B (node 5)
M_reduced = M_reduced_3

M_reduced(3, :) = inf;
M_reduced(:, 2) = inf;
M_reduced(2, 3) = inf;

row_reduction = min(M_reduced, [], 2);

row_reduction(isinf(row_reduction)) = 0;

M_row_reduced = M_reduced - row_reduction;

column_reduction = min(M_row_reduced);

column_reduction(isinf(column_reduction)) = 0;

M_reduced_5 = M_row_reduced - column_reduction;

M_reduced_5(isnan(M_reduced_5)) = inf;

cost_5 = cost_3 + sum(row_reduction) + sum(column_reduction) + M_reduced_3(3, 2)

% Distance between city A, C, D (node 6)
M_reduced = M_reduced_3

M_reduced(3, :) = inf;
M_reduced(:, 4) = inf;
M_reduced(4, 3) = inf;

row_reduction = min(M_reduced, [], 2);

row_reduction(isinf(row_reduction)) = 0;

M_row_reduced = M_reduced - row_reduction;

column_reduction = min(M_row_reduced);

column_reduction(isinf(column_reduction)) = 0;

M_reduced_6 = M_row_reduced - column_reduction;

M_reduced_6(isnan(M_reduced_6)) = inf;

cost_6 = cost_3 + sum(row_reduction) + sum(column_reduction) + M_reduced_3(3, 4)

% Distance between city A, C, D, B (node 7)
M_reduced = M_reduced_3

M_reduced(4, :) = inf;
M_reduced(:, 2) = inf;
M_reduced(2, 4) = inf;

row_reduction = min(M_reduced, [], 2);

row_reduction(isinf(row_reduction)) = 0;

M_row_reduced = M_reduced - row_reduction;

column_reduction = min(M_row_reduced);

column_reduction(isinf(column_reduction)) = 0;

M_reduced_7 = M_row_reduced - column_reduction;

M_reduced_7(isnan(M_reduced_7)) = inf;

cost_7 = cost_3 + sum(row_reduction) + sum(column_reduction) + M_reduced_3(4, 2)
% Optimal path is: A, C, D, B, A with a cost of 25
```

And here the script for generating the distance matrix from a excel file named "test".

```
% column 1: ID for city
% column 2: X coordinate
% column 3: Y coordinate

data = xlsread('Test.xlsx',1)
Dist = dist(data(:,2:3)')
Dist(Dist==0) = inf
```

Best

Comment: Don't write scrips, write functions. You can then write a function that calls your other two functions is sequence and passes data from the one to the other. Also consider learning about loops, your code is way longer and more repetitive than necessary.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I now how to work with For loops. But I'm not sure about the functions. Can you give me an example or a hint?

Comment: MATLAB has excellent tutorials and documentation at the official web site. Here's a page about writing functions: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html  I highly recommend that you work through the tutorials, start here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html